# GCC generates unaligned access for ARMv8

Tags: gcc, arm, memory-alignment

I am setting up a ARMv8 embedded system and stumbled over a hardfault, when trying to compile the following code:

```
void test_ram()
{
    const uint8_t goldendata[16] = { 0xde, 0xad, 0xba, 0xbe, 0, 0x55, 0x55, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0, 0xff, 0xff };
    (void) goldendata;
}
```

Interestingly enough I get a hardfault (unaligned access) when the array is initialized.
GCC apparently even knows that the access is unaligned, as can be seen on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:3),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+test_ram()%0A%7B%0A++++const+uint8_t+goldendata%5B16%5D+%3D+%7B+0xde,+0xad,+0xba,+0xbe,+0,+0x55,+0x55,+0xaa,+0xaa,+0,+0xff,+0xff+%7D%3B%0A++++(void)+goldendata%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:41.89249900987929,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:carmg1320,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc11+-ggdb+-ffunction-sections+-O0+-ggdb+-ffunction-sections+-O0+-Wall++-mcpu%3Dcortex-m33+-mthumb+-mfpu%3Dfpv5-sp-d16++-mfloat-abi%3Dhard%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+ARM+GCC+13.2.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:22.222222222222218,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+ARM+GCC+13.2.0+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:58.107500990120684,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

[image]

Compiled with GCC 13.2 ARM, options `-std=c11 -ggdb -ffunction-sections -O0 -ggdb -ffunction-sections -O0 -Wall  -mcpu=cortex-m33 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16  -mfloat-abi=hard`

## Question

Why would GCC generate an array initialization which results in a hard fault?

I am not sure if the unaligned access necessitates a hard fault, since I found conflicitng arm documentation (unaligned access always faults vs faults iff `UNALIGN_TRP` bit is set):

Arm® v8-M Architecture Reference Manual DDI0553B.l
B6.4 Alignment behavior

> The following are unaligned data accesses that always generate an
> alignment fault: • Non halfword-aligned LDAH, LDREXH, LDAEXH, STLH,
> STLEXH, and STREXH. • Non word-aligned LDREX, LDAEX, STLEX, STREX,
> LDRD, LDMIA, LDMDB, POP (multiple registers), LDC, VLDR, VLDM, VPOP,
> LDA, STL, STMIA, STMDB, PUSH (mulitple registers), STC, VSTR, VSTM,
> VPUSG, VLLDM, and VLSTM. Applies to an implementation of the
> architecture from Armv8.0-M onwards

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100235/0002/jds1485977091086

> Unaligned accesses are usually slower than aligned accesses. In
> addition, some memory regions might not support unaligned accesses.
> Therefore, Arm recommends that programmers ensure that accesses are
> aligned. To trap accidental generation of unaligned accesses, use the
> UNALIGN_TRP bit in the Configuration and Control Register.

I checked the UNALIGN_TRP bit (bit 3), and it is not set, yet I end up with the fault. (`gdb x/x 0xE000ED14` => `0xe000ed14:    0x00000201`)

If it makes any difference the CPU used is a CortexM33 in the STM32U5.

Footnote: I found I can suppress the issue either by making the variable static (aka not allocating the array unaligned on the stack) or by passing gcc the `-mno-unaligned-access` option

Comment: I don't see any conflicting information.  Unaligned access always traps for the listed instructions (which are all either atomic, memory-barrier, or wider than 32 bits), but that list does not include plain `str/strh/ldr/ldrh`.  The system designer can decide whether to allow other unaligned accesses by setting `UNALIGN_TRP`.  gcc defaults to assuming they are allowed, and will generate them where it finds it appropriate to do so; but as you saw, you can alter that with `-mno-unaligned-access`.

Comment: Are you running under an OS, or bare-metal?  If under an OS, check its ABI documentation as to whether unaligned accesses are supposed to be allowed.  If it's bare metal, do you *want* to allow unaligned accesses?  If no, then just use `-mno-unaligned-access` and be happy.  If yes, then the question becomes, why isn't it working?

Comment: First, show the code for how you are testing the `UNALIGN_TRP` flag, in case there is a bug there.  Note this register is only directly readable by privileged code; if your code is unprivileged, the OS might trap and emulate the access, so that it appears to work but the values returned may or may not reflect the actual machine state.  Also, can you verify that your program is running entirely in `Normal` memory rather than `Device`?

Comment: @NateEldredge: 1) You are right, clearly I read the information to fast and it is not conflicting. But why do I get a fault then? 2) I checked the `UNALIGN_TRP` flag using the gdb command quoted in the answer (`gdb x/x 0xE000ED14`) 3) I am running using FreeRTOS, but thought that the OS should not matter, its the hardware generating the hardfault, and it does not look like the OS configured the hardware to disallow unaligned access.

Comment: I am 99% sure the code runs in `Normal` memory: I have not implemented a loader for the external flash, and the linker file only knows about device ram/flash, and external ram/flash. Given that there is no loader for the external Flash, and it has not been mapped I cant imagine yet, how the code should run somewhere else.

Comment: @NateEldredge Currently I do not make use of Trustzone (Priviledged/Unpriviledgged Code), thus I assume I should see the correct register value, but that might be a good point. Can you please point me in a direction of keywords or sections I should study in the documentation to see if the `UNALIGN_TRP` bit is actually set and I see a wrong value? Given that I know that the `strh` instruction traps, are there any other explanations for the trap than me not getting the actual `UNALIGN_TRP` bit value? (I dont just want to be happy, I want to understand)

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100235/0002/the-cortex-m33-processor/memory-model/behavior-of-memory-accesses?lang=en shows the address ranges and their types, so you could compare that against the value in `r3` when the fault occurs.  But no, if you're certain that it is actually the `strh` instruction that traps, then I can't think of any other explanation besides `UNALIGN_TRP` or `Device` memory.  It comes immediately after successful stores to adjacent words on both sides of the offending address, so the memory must be otherwise valid.

Comment: Thanks, for what its worth the alignement requirements for `Device` memory was news to me so I learned something.

Comment: @NateEldredge in case you care: you were right the memory got assigned Device type via the MPU. I failed to consider that CubeMX might generate code to initialize the MPU with values which conflict what the documentation you linked and I used specify as defaults for the internal Flash/RAM. Thanks for all the pointers.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out @Nate Eldredge was right:

Using CubeMX code to enable the MPU was generated, for some reason Cube chose to mark the internal flash and the internal memory as `Device`. Ammending manual initializaiton code to set the memory as normal memory fixes the issue. Snippet of copy pasta CubeMX code. Simply adding the Macro `INNER_OUTER` for the attributes remedies the issue. (apply for Flash and RAM, see which region numbers cube used)

```
HAL_MPU_Disable();
    
MPU_AttributesInit.Number = MPU_REGION_NUMBER1; // pretty sure this should be MPU_ATTRIBUTES_NUMBER1 but since attributes and region number are defined to the same values, we stick with ST's initialisation here...
MPU_AttributesInit.Attributes = INNER_OUTER( MPU_WRITE_BACK | MPU_TRANSIENT | MPU_RW_ALLOCATE );

HAL_MPU_ConfigMemoryAttributes(&MPU_AttributesInit);
HAL_MPU_Enable(MPU_PRIVILEGED_DEFAULT);
```